# SELECT set of rows between two non-null column values in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for an efficient way to select a set of rows from a table, perform some checks on the SET (like count) then moves to next SET of rows.

The criteria for row selection is to get all the rows in-between of two rows that have some non-null value in one column.

For example, in the following table i have a column "PACKAGE_ID". First record has an ID of 1A and the next 2 records do not have any ID - means they are part of the 1A package.

In this particular example, i would like to get 3 distinct SETS

```
1st set : PRODUCT ID 34, 23, 14
2nd set : PRODUCT ID 48
3rd set : PRODUCT ID 75, 11
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ PRODUCT_ID             PACKAGE_ID       SORT_SEQUENCE           ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ ---------------------- ----------       ----------------------  ║
║ 34                     1A               1001                    ║
║ 23                     (null)           1002                    ║
║ 14                     (null)           1003                    ║
║ 48                     2B               1004                    ║
║ 75                     3C               1005                    ║
║ 11                     (null)           1006                    ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

one way i would think is to use LAG/LEAD functions in a CURSOR and select rows in sequential manner and once a next non-null value is spotted, perform the operation on previous rows before moving to the next.

However, i'm wondering if there is a better way to do the logic on SETS rather than going row by row? Any advice / direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Gordon has already provided an efficient and general solution for your generic problem statement. It would be interesting what "operation" you are performing on the rows of a group, and what your Oracle version is (as reported by `select * from v$version`). For example, it is possible that the `match_recognize` clause, introduced in version 12.1, will do quick work of your row operations - even faster than the analytic function solutions. (But only available in Oracle 12.1 and above!)

Comment: no, i am on Oracle 10g so cant use anything introduced in later versions. I would need to do sum of one of the coilumns based on the sets and then group them as single package based on some rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum/count to assign the sets:

```
select t.*,
       count(package_id) over (order by sort_sequence) as set_id
from t;
```

The `count()` counts the number of non-NULL values up to each row.  That is the set id that you are looking for.

Comment: yes, i can build up the logic on the basis of those set_ids. Thanks Gordon!